# I need to compare two rows of data for duplicate

Tags: mysql

I need to compare two rows of data for duplicate, if the consecutive rows are the same activityID I need to notate one is in error. This code is not working as I wish

[image: This should throw an error]

My code is not testing correctly.

```
SELECT
  CASE  
         WHEN activityId = activityId +1 THEN activityId = 'error' 
          ELSE activityId = activityId 
       END AS sortOrder,recordId,
                        activityId,
                        started,
                        completed,
                        userId

    FROM log1644
```

Comment: Please post sample data and desired output in textual form.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the next or previous row like that. To be exact, there actually is not really a next or previous row, meaning that in a database data has no specific order when you don't specify it. As long as you don't have an `ORDER BY one_or_multiple_columns` in your query, the result you get back might get displayed in another order each time you issue your query.
That said, you have two possibilities:

- join the table to itself
- use variables

Joining the table to itself would work something like this

```
SELECT * FROM table alias_a 
INNER JOIN table alias_b ON a.id = b.id + 1
```

Then a `CASE WHEN a.whatever = b.whatever THEN 'error' ELSE 'cool' END` would work, but this can become ugly pretty quickly, for example when the next id is not `+1` but sometimes `+2` because you deleted a row sometime or other causes. Or performancewise this can be bad, anyway...

I prefer using variables for cases like this.

```
SELECT
yt.*,
CASE WHEN @prevID = id THEN 'oops, same id as row before' ELSE 'another_id' END AS is_it_different,
@prevID := id
FROM your_table yt,
(SELECT @prevID := 0) table_alias__variable_initialization
ORDER BY id, another_column_determining_the_order_of_ids
```

As mentioned earlier, the `ORDER BY` is important here.
In the `CASE WHEN ...` the variable `@prevID` still has the value of the previous row. In the next line of the statement, the value of the current row gets assigned to the variable.